# Working with Enums in Thymeleaf 3 (Spring Boot 3)

Tags: spring-boot, enums, thymeleaf, spring-el

I'm attempting to upgrade an application to Spring Boot 3.0.6 from 2.2.6, and while I've resolved a lot of the issues, a Thymeleaf issue is causing problems.

I've previously followed [the Baeldung tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-enums) to implement a series of checkboxes based on an enum to store user preferences. Prior to the upgrade this was working fine - a stripped back version of the code in question is:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    SOME(true, OtherClass.class),
    VALUES(true, OtherClass.class),
    FOR(true, OtherClass.class),
    THE(false, AnotherClass.class),
    ENUM(false, AnotherClass.class);

    //constructor, so on

    private boolean configurable;
    private Class<?> relatedClass;
}

//lombok
@Data
public class FormDTO {

    private List<MyEnum> myField;

}

<input type="checkbox" th:each="item : ${T(my.app.MyEnum).values()}" 
    th:if="${item.configurable == true and item.relatedClass == T(my.app.OtherClass)}"
    name="myField" th:value="${item}" th:checked="${#lists.contains(selectedItems, item)}" />
```

The iteration still works - as does the first SpEL expression comparing the related class. However, the `#lists.contains()` now evaluates to `false`, as does swapping it for `selectedItems.contains(item)` - however `selectedItems.contains(item)` evaluates to `true` if it is ran anywhere else in the application, prior to it being added to the template.

Additionally, adding `MyEnum.values()` as a model attribute rather than accessing it using SpEL returns `true` for `#lists.contains()` - but then the `item.relatedClass == T(my.app.OtherClass)` checks return `false` regardless.

I've been able to get *something* working by adding a utility method that maps the `myField` values to a `List<String>` so that I can amend the `th:checked` to effectively be `#lists.contains(myField.getEnumNames(), item.name)` but this seems like a suboptimal solution - does anyone have any pointers as to if/how the treatment of Enums in Thymeleaf 3 has changed which might cause this change in behaviour?

Comment: I haven't been able to narrow this down exactly, but it isn't Thymeleaf or SpEL, at least not directly. This seems like a build issue of some kind, maybe to do with DevTools. I use Eclipse, and fully stopping the application, running maven clean, and starting it up again solves the problem - but I'm not going to answer with this in case someone knows more.